# Data is not inserting to database but retrieving is working fine using PHP and Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Before I ask you my question I want to clarify that I'm just a rookie to Ajax and Jquery, so please spare me if the doubt is very small or a piece of cake, sorry for that.

I'm trying to create review system for my E-Commerce using Ajax and PHP. The problem is, the data is not inserting in to the database, but if I insert the the data manually in the database it displaying perfectly in my site.I think there is something going wrong with the variable review or user_review but couldn't find what it is.So, could you please tell me where I've done the mistake.

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="reviews">
    <h4>Write your Review</h4>
    <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return post();">
        <textarea id="review" class="reviewbox" placeholder="Write Your Review Here....."></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div id="all_reviews">
        <?php
                            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE product_id=?");
                            $query -> bindValue(1, $id);
                            $query->execute();
                            while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            {
                                $name = $row['user_name'];
                                $text = $row['review_text'];
                                $time = $row['post_time'];
                        ?>
            <h5>By <?php echo $name; ?></h5>
            <p><i>posted on <?php echo $time; ?></i></p>
            <p>
                <?php echo $text; ?>
            </p>
            <hr>
            <?php
                            }
                        ?>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
    < script type = "text/javascript" >
        function post() {
            var review = document.getElementById("review").value;
            if (review) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'post_reviews.php',
                    data: {
                        user_review: review
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        document.getElementById("all_reviews").innerHTML = response + document.getElementById("all_reviews").innerHTML;
                        document.getElementById("review").value = "";
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

This is my `post_reviews.php`:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    require('includes/product.php');
    require('includes/connect.php');
    $product = new Product;         
    if(isset ($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $data = $product -> fetch_data($id);    

        if(isset($_POST['user_review'])){
            $review=$_POST['user_review'];
            if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
                $query = $pdo -> prepare("INSERT INTO reviews(product_id,user_name,review_text) VALUES (?,?,?)");
                $query -> bindValue(1, $id);
                $query -> bindValue(2, $_SESSION['name']);
                $query -> bindValue(3,$review);
                $query ->execute();
            }
            else{
                $review_msg="Please login to post your review";
            }
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE product_id=?");
            $query -> bindValue(1, $id);
            $query->execute();
            while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $name = $row['user_name'];
                $text = $row['review_text'];
                $time = $row['post_time'];
?>
                <?php if(isset($review_msg)){ ?>
                    <small style = "color : #aa0000"; ><?php echo $review_msg ?></small>
                    <br><br>
                <?php } ?>
                <h5>By <?php echo $name; ?></h5>
                <p><i>posted on <?php echo $time; ?></i></p>
                <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
                <hr>
<?php 
            }
        }
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your ajax code is working or not please check it in your console.??

Comment: Can you share your table structure? Also...I think your $_GET['id'] is not set and that's why your insert is not working. Try to pass the id in ajax data and use $_POST the same way you used it for review.

Comment: you can simply debug the code by using print / write in a file, print the insert query and then run it manually.

Comment: @Vladut No, if that's the case it would have shown an error and also tried by making id row as NULL default and still the same.

My table structure is like this..

`rid (Primary)   int(11)   AI`
`product_id    int(20)`
`user_name    text`
`review_text    text`
`post_time`

Comment: @ggupta you mean something like this print_r($review);If yes I have tried and it showed nothing.

Comment: First thing: print_r("something") at the begining of the file post_review.php (check ajax response using network tab in chrome dev tools. Or you can add error function and console.log something on success and error to see if everything is ok with your ajax call. If this is working fine, check your connection with the database if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake you have done your script code is not closed

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
```

To

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

That is the reason your ajax is not working.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work.and console is also empty that means no errors.

Answer (score 0):

first check your ajax working or not on button click

Answer (score 0):

var review = document.getElementById("review").value;

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post_reviews.php",
    data: review,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        document.getElementById("all_reviews").innerHTML = response + document.getElementById("all_reviews").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("review").value = "";
    }


});

return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I see. You are submiting the form.

```
 <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return post();">
        <textarea id="review" class="reviewbox" placeholder="Write Your Review 
         Here....."></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Try to replace your form with this:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
  <textarea id="review" class="reviewbox" placeholder="Write Your Review 
             Here....."></textarea>
  <button type="button" onclick="post()" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If button type is "button" it will not submit the form. And by clicking it now will call your function and execute ajax call.